# Disable Visual Effects

Tags: windows-7, visual-effects

I am transforming Windows 7 into Windows XP. When I highlight icons, it has a sky blue highlight. But XP has solid blue like Windows 95. How can I disable these sky blue visual effects?

Answer (score 1):

Disable Windows Aero, which is responsible for the glossy UI and transparency:

1. Go to `start -> control panel`
2. In the `Appearance and Personalization` section, click `customize color`.
3. Click `Open classic Appearance Properties for more color options`.
4. Select a color scheme other than Windows Aero and click OK.